# Вывести текстовый документ в консоль, C

Tags: c

Есть текстовый документ, там что-то по типу инструкции, как этот текст вывести в консоль?

Comment: Открыть файл, читать из него и выводить на консоль - в файл `stdout`...

Comment: А можно поподробнее узнать про stdout?

Comment: `printf()` пишет в stdout.

Comment: Конечно! В любом учебнике по C.

Comment: Идиоматически -- `FILE *f = fopen(...);int c; while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) putchar(c);`